# Bind sqlite database with custom iOS framework

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, resources, ios-frameworks

I have developed a custom ios framework for achieving some task, which is working perfectly but I have to add my sqlite database separately in my test app. I want to bind my sqlite database with my custom framework so that it will automatically added in any app where user want to user that framework.

I also don't want to show sqlite database to anyone. can anyone please tell me the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you got the answer? I am searching for the same. Can you put the answer..

Comment: HI Vinod ,  
did you got the answer? I am searching for the same. can you help me if you get

Comment: @venkipar. Not get the answer but I have put the whole database on my backend server and get an search API. So whatever data required I get that using my own API. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @VinodSingh  Thank you .. i will check

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking to ship a sqlite database with your app, and have it installed invisibly to the user.  Just add the database to your NSBundle, by including it in the application.  The important part is that you must copy this bundled database to the file system (you probably want to also mark it as not being in the cloud), because the NSBundle'd files are read-only.  So, here's your strategy:  1) on startup, check to see if the database is in the file system. 2) if not, copy it from the NSBundle to the file system, 3) open the database in the file system.

Comment: I want to distribute my framework N people, but don't want them to see the content of sqlite. I am looking for a solution which allow me to bind database with my custom framework, so if user add framework in their app database will automatically with framework just like a image bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better solution to your question but here is a suggestion on what you could: [Programmatically create the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545520/how-to-create-sqlite-database-programmatically) in your framework. As for hiding the database [here is the solution to that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864823/hide-core-data-sqlite-file-when-itunes-file-sharing-is-enabled)! You may also [encrypt the sqlite file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381264/password-protect-a-sqlite-db-is-it-possible).

Cheers