# disable access to app's directory in Organizer

Tags: iphone, application-settings

I want to disable the "download data" capability [for my app] in Organizer.  I belive it's a plist file setting but can't find information on it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking of UIFileSharingEnabled, but that doesn't quite stop people, as reported in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942855/iphone-documents-directory-and-uifilesharingenabled-hiding-certain-documents). That answer also links to an Apple doc that advises creating a custom directory in [app home]/Library/, something like "Private Documents" (make sure the folder name is unique), since Library/ is maintained in backups and upgrades and hidden from the user. See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1699.html).