# Documents Directory With UIFileSharingEnable

Tags: iphone, ios, file-sharing, nsdocumentdirectory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Documents directory and UIFileSharingEnabled, hiding certain documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942855/iphone-documents-directory-and-uifilesharingenabled-hiding-certain-documents)

I want the user to be able to transfer some files to my app documents directory through iTunes ..I already did that and everything is working fine .. but my problem that I don't want the user to see all the document files there is some files like the "sqlite db" shouldn't be accessible by users since it really will make big problem's if the user delete or change it ... I make some research and some people say you have to store these files in the Library/Preferences .. but after I check some application that support file sharing i can see files thats appear in the its document directory (through iphone explorer) but not in the iTunes!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the answer .. its very simple , you just need to put dot "." at the beginning of the file name and it will be hidden in iTunes !

Answer (score 0):

place all the file which you do not want to show in itunes, in a subfolder in documents directory.

Comment: thanks for the answer i know that you can't see the files in subfolder  .. but still some app have files at root and its hidden .. check "Kobo" for example.